# Write Propostion using Quantifier

Tags: logic

Write the proposition “Every pair of strangers has a common friend” using connectives and quantifiers. Use F(x, y) for “x is friends with y.” (Two people are strangers if they are not friends.)

My idea is that for any pair of strangers (x,y), there exists a person z that is F(x,z) and F(y,z), but how to write that in quantifier form?

Comment: How would you write the statement " For any pair of strangers $(x, y)$ " using quantifiers? Or more simply how would you represent "strangers" as a proposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say $$\forall x, y \left(\lnot F(x,y)\Rightarrow \exists z \left(F(x,z)\wedge F(y,z)\right)\right)$$

Comment: I think I understand now, its for all x,y, which x and y are not friends, there exists someone z that z is both friends with x and y. Thank you!

Comment: Yes :) with other words, IF $x$ and $y$ are not friend ($\lnot F(x,y)$) THEN exists $z$ that is friend with both.

Comment: This works if there isn't anyone that isn't friends with themselves. I guess we can assume that's implicit in the friendship predicate, otherwise we need an equality predicate to indicate x and y aren't equal.